# Simple RNN(LSTM) model doesn't make progress

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have `np_final_x(71520, 2, 50)` and `np_final_y(71520, 1, 50)` corpus

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k15dtcak78jaf34/np_final_x_len_2.npy?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/555lhbdnkl6gmrq/np_final_y_len_2.npy?dl=0

This means predict like this `I use -> this`,
`you give -> me`

predict next word from two words.

And each words are encoded into 50 dimension vector.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np

final_x = np.load('np_final_x_len_2.npy')
final_y = np.load('np_final_y_len_2.npy')

in_out_neurons = 50
n_hidden = 512 # not so much change
#n_hidden = 1 # not so much change
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_hidden, batch_input_shape=(None, 2, in_out_neurons), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(in_out_neurons,activation="tanh")) #not so much change
#model.add(Dense(in_out_neurons,activation="sigmoid")) #not so much change
#model.add(Dense(in_out_neurons, activation="relu"))   #not so much change
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer)

model.summary()
model.fit(         
    final_x,final_y,
    batch_size=400,
    epochs=10,
    validation_split=0.1
)
```

However what I got was around 0.017~0.019 not so much progress, even I changed any parameters.

Moreover, even when `n_hidden = 1`,result doesn't change.

So I guess something is wrong basically.

appreciate any help and hints. thank you.

```
Epoch 1/10
161/161 [==============================] - 9s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0195 - val_loss: 0.0192
Epoch 2/10
161/161 [==============================] - 8s 49ms/step - loss: 0.0191 - val_loss: 0.0188
Epoch 3/10
161/161 [==============================] - 8s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0187 - val_loss: 0.0186
Epoch 4/10
161/161 [==============================] - 11s 68ms/step - loss: 0.0185 - val_loss: 0.0184
Epoch 5/10
161/161 [==============================] - 12s 77ms/step - loss: 0.0184 - val_loss: 0.0183
Epoch 6/10
161/161 [==============================] - 13s 83ms/step - loss: 0.0183 - val_loss: 0.0183
Epoch 7/10
161/161 [==============================] - 14s 85ms/step - loss: 0.0183 - val_loss: 0.0182
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to predict from two word embeddings the next word. It doesn't make sense to set `return_sequences` to `True` in the LSTM. I played a bit with your data and model, my best mse validation is 0.015 The limitation comes from the data and the simplistic model to predict the next word from two consecutive words (would a human be able to do that?) . Also, how do you get the 50 dimensional word embedding? It would be interesting to be able to go back to the words and see what kind of prediction the model produces.

Comment: I use `Word2Vec` `http://public.shiroyagi.s3.amazonaws.com/latest-ja-word2vec-gensim-model.zip`  (sorry this is for japanese ) And you can get back words like this `from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec` `wv_model = Word2Vec.load(model_path)` `wv_model.similar_by_vector(word_vector,topn=1)[0])`

Comment: In my learning, result is always looping just two words or only one word `'迷う',’あちこち','迷う',’あちこち','迷う',あちこち'`,`'あちこち','あちこち','あちこち','あちこち'`